# Keyframes animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Is there a way I could simplify this with Sass or JS? It works, but it's not what I'd call 'DRY' code. An alternate form I've tried is a Sass `for` loop but can't get it to work.

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  color: black;
  font-size: 55px;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgb(167, 167, 167);
  animation: fill 1s;
}

@keyframes fill {
 0% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 }
 2.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025);
 }
 5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 }
 7.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
 }
 10% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 }
 12.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
 }
 15% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 }
 17.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
 }
 20% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 }
 22.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.225);
 }
 25% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 }
 27.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.275);
 }
 30% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 }
 32.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.325);
 }
 35% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
 }
 37.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.375);
 }
 40% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 }
 42.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.425);
 }
 45% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
 }
 47.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.475);
 }
 50% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 }
 52.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.525);
 }
 55% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
 }
 57.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.575);
 }
 60% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 }
 62.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.625);
 }
 65% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
 }
 67.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.675);
 }
 70% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 }
 72.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.725);
 }
 75% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 }
 77.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.775);
 }
 80% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 }
 82.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.825);
 }
 85% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
 }
 87.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.875);
 }
 90% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
 }
 92.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.925);
 }
 95% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
 }
 97.5% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.975);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 }
}
```

```html
<h1>This Is A Test</h1>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, I would make a special class for the style instead of having it as a style for all `h1`'s.

You can IMO simplify the `keyframes` quite a bit in the following way:

```css
.fade-in {
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  font-size: 55px;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgb(167, 167, 167);
  animation-timing-function: steps(50, end);
  animation: fill 2s;
}

@keyframes fill {
  0% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fade-in">This Is A Test</h1>
```

When I test it on my computer it seems to be the same effect.

`-webkit-text-fill-color` [isn't standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color), so I wouldn't rely on using it at all.

Comment: Good thinking. I knew there was a better way!